# how to configure RN xv 171 module for UART communication?

Tags: wifi

Heyy, I am using the RN xv 171 module along with stm32f4 discovery board. I wish to communicate with the module over uart from the board. However, the module is either mute or echoing the messages sent over UART. I have done the configuration to be done in the ad-hoc mode, as given in the user manual. I would like to know if any other configuration changes are required? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the "RN xv 171 module"

Comment: @LeonHeller Probably meant wifi chip RN171XV of Roving networks

Comment: @Gundeep, to make this question more clear, specify what you mean by "the configuration to be done" . Else we can't tell what you did or didn't

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried telnet to it? that's one way to check if you configured it right.

Also make sure there's a positive communication between the UART module in the stm32f4 and the rn 171 chip itself  (baud rate, parity, etc..)
Default is 9,600 baud, 8 bits, no parity, 1 stop bit and disabled flow control

As far as configuration using Ad Hoc mode,

1. Set your SSID (XX, last two bytes): WiFly-GSX-XX
2. DHCP (on or off)
3. The channel
4. IP address (to telnet to)
5. Netmask

p.s. make sure there's an antenna, usually RN131 comes with On-board antenna, not sure about RN171/XV

note: used this manual
http://www.rovingnetworks.com/resources/download/93/wifly_user_manual

Comment: thanks for the reply. I actually want to use the wifi module to run a 'scan' at some points, but I am not able to receive information from the module as it is simply echoing the commands sent.For the 'configuration' part,I have followed the same user manual.I don't want the module to get connected to any particular network,but just want it to run a scan and return the mac address and RSS values.I have configured it using telnet where I am able to run the scan on my laptop,and also made sure the UART specs match.I have 'saved' the configuration in the telnet session,as written in manual.

Comment: @Gundeep, Can you tell me exactly what you typed?

Comment: well i typed the following after entering the command mode in telnet session.
set wlan join 0
save
get uart status (checked if it matched with the uart specs on the microcontroller)
set uart mode ox10 (tried ox00 as well)
save